# Convert RGB values to color wheel coordinates

Tags: android, math, colors

I have a picture of a color wheel from google and now I would like to find a way to somehow calculate the x and y coordinates of any rgb color in the color wheel.
If that was a little bit confusing Ill try to explain it a little bit better:
I have a picture of a color wheel - like you have in paint.net to select a color. I also have a color in form of rgb values. Now I want to get the x and y coordinates of the picture that have exactly that color.
I however do not have any idea how one could do that. I am trying to use this in an App created with MIT App Inventor 2, what limits my abilities a little. So the best thing would be a mathematical only solution.
I hope someone here can help me with this.

Edit: So here you have the picture I'm using. I actually wanted to have this in here all the time, but forgot it...

[image]

Comment: How do you expect we should guess exact characteristics of the "color wheel" you use? Or how we are supposed to give you an answer without knowing such details?

Comment: You need to find an equation for the different colors. My guess is that you have constant level for one color on each third of the external circle. 255 for red on the top, 255 for the blue bottom left, and 255 green bottom right. Outside of their zone, each color intensity decreases to go to 0 at the middle of the next zone. This stands for the external circle, but you'll probably need to extend this result to get from the side to the center. However, you should try to code it first, and then come back to us for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experimenting with implementing a color picker in my iOS app [using CIFilter](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/cifilter-colorwheel/) and had to solve the same problem.

I discovered that HSV values for a given color map pretty nicely to that color wheel:

- `hue` is the angle around the wheel. 0 or 1 is 0 or 2pi radians, 0.75 is pi/2, 0.5 is pi, etc. Basically it goes from 1 to 0 around the circle clockwise starting at the far right.
- `saturation` is how far you are from the center of the circle to the edge, as a percentage of the radius. 0 in the middle, 1 at the edge.
- `value` is the darkness of the color (`inputValue` in the post I linked to above).

So, given `hue` and `saturation` for a given color, see this psuedocode:

```
float pickerWidth = myPickerImage.size.width;
float radius = pickerWidth / 2;
float colorRadius = saturation * radius;
float angle = (1 - hue) * (2 * pi);
float midX = myPicker.size.width / 2; //midpoint of the circle
float midY = myPicker.size.height / 2;
float xOffset = cos(angle) * colorRadius; //offset from the midpoint of the circle
float yOffset = sin(angle) * colorRadius;
Point colorPoint = new Point(midX + xOffset, midY + yOffset);
```

The `value` parameter would be used to implement a darkness slider.

You'll need to convert RGB to HSV - `UIColor` does this for me automatically, but I bet there's a way to do it on Android too.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I will take a look at implementing it in my project.